# Authorize through Oauth 1.0 with Magento API through Postman

Tags: php, api, magento, oauth

I set up a test Magento Community 1.9 and am trying to test my third party application which connects to Magento API. The Magento API is running on a localhost XAMPP server.I am testing my connection to API with Postman.
I run the following connection in Postman:

> http://nazariys-macbook-pro.local/magento-1/oauth/initiate?oauth_consumer_key=dc41f11be0efb0124c7f9fcf962cc2ac&oauth_signature_method=HMAC-SHA1&oauth_timestamp=1452629068&oauth_nonce=puFenO&oauth_version=1.0&oauth_signature=vBqz9VyBc2zn6R3UDPg1tDylKqE=

I did add myself in the admin panel and got the secret key.

My response is this:

```
oauth_problem=parameter_absent&oauth_parameters_absent=oauth_callback
```

I have tried adding different callbacks like localhost or http://httpbin.org/get and keep getting the same problem.

I am sorry but I am new to Oauth and Magento, so I am asking if you can please let me know what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Put this snippet code in the body:

```
oauth_callback="http://yourhost/oauth_admin.php"
```